# SQL: How to display rhombus shape based on given length of characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My requirement is to build a rhombus using ‘X’ symbol based on below conditions.
If the length is 2, then it should display

```
 X
XXX
 X
```

If the length is 3, then it should display

```
  X
 XXX
XXXXX
 XXX
  X
```

If the length is 5, then it should display 5 lines above and 5 lines below with spaces.

I tried writing code, but I’m unable to get lower half part and spaces. Can someone help me here?

```
declare @X nvarchar(1) = 'X'
declare @chars int = 5
declare @W nvarchar(100) = 1

while (@chars > 0)
begin
print replicate(@X,@W)
set @chars = @chars - 1
set @W = @W + 2
end
```

**Output:**

```
X
XXX
XXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get spaces using `SPACE` function. I have used your approach and added some code which returns lower part as well.

```
DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(1) = 'X'
DECLARE @chars INT = 5
DECLARE @LowerPart INT = @chars
DECLARE @W NVARCHAR(100) = 1

WHILE (@chars > 0)
    BEGIN
    PRINT SPACE(@chars)+REPLICATE(@X,@W)
    SET @chars = @chars - 1
    SET @W = @W + 2
    END
WHILE (@chars <= @LowerPart)
    BEGIN
    PRINT SPACE(@chars)+REPLICATE(@X,@W)
    SET @chars = @chars + 1
    SET @W = @W - 2
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I've considered your example rhombus for 3. So, for a given length 5, there will be only 4 lines above and 4 lines below with my solution.

```
declare @displayCharacter nvarchar(1) = 'X'
declare @rhombusLength int = 5
declare @repetition int = 1
declare @topRow int = 1
declare @bottomRow int = 1

--Top rows
while (@rhombusLength > @topRow)
begin
    print REPLICATE(' ', @rhombusLength - @topRow) + REPLICATE(@displayCharacter, @repetition)
    set @topRow = @topRow + 1
    set @repetition = @repetition + 2
end

--Middle row
print REPLICATE(@displayCharacter, @repetition)

--Bottom rows
while (@rhombusLength > @bottomRow)
begin
    set @repetition = @repetition - 2
    print REPLICATE(' ', @bottomRow) + REPLICATE(@displayCharacter, @repetition)
    set @bottomRow = @bottomRow + 1 
end
```